# Unable to use dirname within subshell in find command

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am trying to make a small script that can move all files from one directory to another, and I figured using find would be the best solution. However, I have run into a problem of using subshells for the 'dirname' value in creating the target directory paths. This does not work because {} evaluates to '.' (a single dot) when inside a subshell. As seen in my script bellow, the `-exec mkdir -p $toDir/$(dirname {}) \;` portion of the find command is what does not work. I want to create all of the target directories needed to move the files, but I cannot use dirname in a subshell to get only the directory path.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory containting files to deploy relative to this script
fromDir=../deploy
# directory where the files should be moved to relative to this script
toDir=../main

if [ -d "$fromDir" ]; then
    if [ -d "$toDir" ]; then
        toDir=$(cd $toDir; pwd)
        cd $fromDir
        find * -type f -exec echo "Moving file [$(pwd)/{}] to [$toDir/{}]" \; -exec mkdir -p $toDir/$(dirname {}) \; -exec mv {} $toDir/{} \;
    else
        echo "A directory named '$toDir' does not exist relative to this script"
    fi
else
    echo "A directory named '$fromDir' does not exist relative to this script" 
fi
```

I know that you can us `-exec sh -c 'echo $(dirname {})' \;`, but with this, I would then not be able to use the $toDir variable.

Can anyone help me figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: I not understand `-exec mkdir -p $toDir/$(dirname {}) \;` because you have `todir` path and simply move to that. why you require to create dir?

Comment: I need to create the directories (including parents) for all of the target files before I attempt to move them because the mv command will not create non-existing directories when moving files.

Comment: Well I finally just figured it out. All I had to do was export the $toDir variable so that it was accessible to the subshell...

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be re-creating all the files and directories, try the `tar` trick:

```
mkdir $toDir
cd $fromDir
tar -cf - . | ( cd $toDir ; tar -xvf - )
```